# Modify column of a data.table based on another column and add the new column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` `DT` with two columns

```
   V1 V2
1:  1  3
2:  2  4
3:  3  5
4:  2  2
5:  3  8
6:  1  4
7:  2  5
```

For each row I want to take all the entries with the same `V1` and add the `V2` entries then divide the `V2` entry by that sum and add in a third column.  For example, in row 1, column 3 the answer should be 3/(3+4).  In row 2, column 3 the answer should be 4/(4+2+5), etc.

Ultimately I should have

```
   V1 V2 V3
1:  1  3 0.4285714
2:  2  4 0.3636364
3:  3  5 0.3846154
4:  2  2 0.1818182
5:  3  8 0.6153846
6:  1  4 0.5714286
7:  2  5 0.4545455
```

I can get `V3` via `q <- DT[,V2/sum(V2),by='V1']` but then the rows are in the wrong order

```
   V1        V1
1:  1 0.4285714
2:  1 0.5714286
3:  2 0.3636364
4:  2 0.1818182
5:  2 0.4545455
6:  3 0.3846154
7:  3 0.6153846
```

so simply pasting the second column of `q` to `DT` will not work.  Also, somewhat awkwardly the `data.table` `q` now has two columns with the same name, `V1`.

I have been banging my head on this problem for a few days now, searched high and low and still cannot come up with a simple answer.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Create a *new* table using

```
DT[,list(V2=V2, V3=V2/sum(V2)), by='V1']
```

(with modified row order) or *modify* the `data.table` in place using the assignment operator:

```
DT[, V3 := V2/sum(V2), by='V1']
```

Note that now the row order is the same.

Please [RTFM](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) (half the questions I ask about `data.table` I could have answered myself if I spent an extra 30 minutes perusing [it](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf)!)

As for the row order in the new table, I don't think you can easily preserve it.
It is also unclear why you would want to preserve the order unless there is another column which dictates it already, in which case you can sort the new table accordingly.

Comment: First thank you for the answer!  That works in that at least the calculations are appended correctly.  If I may, why does this work? A minor issue is that the rows are in the wrong order.  I suppose that I can fix the latter issue by appending a new column with the row numbers and sorting on it.  However, is there a "one step" solution?

Comment: Please see the edit: grouping requires sorting to be efficient.